# WordPress - Get Page ID of the shortcode included page

Tags: php, wordpress

Lets say I have **"myshortcode"** as a shortcode. I have inserted this shortcode in wordpress page **(pageid = 1)** using [myshortcode].

How would I get the id of the page in the code files? I searched and got this solution that seems to give me the ID.

```
global $wpdb;

$PageID = $wpdb->get_var('SELECT ID FROM '.$table_prefix.'posts WHERE post_content LIKE "%[myshortcode]%" AND post_parent = 0');
```

But the problem is it returns the page id as a string. So I can't seem to use it numerically.

For example, if I use it in wp_redirect, I get error that **the page is not redirecting properly**.

I tried **(int)$PageID** but the doesn't seem to fix the problem.

Any help?

Comment: Have you tried the get_the_ID() function in wordpress? The get_the_ID() function returns an integer. That way you won't call $wpdb and perform db query. Source: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_id/

Comment: I am not in the loop. I am working outside the loop. Its actually a plugin that will redirect the user. So long story shot, I am outside the loop and get_the_ID won't work.

Comment: I see. That's really weird that (int)$PageID return as string. Have you also tried intval($PageID)?

Comment: Yup. That doesn't work too. It actually works for normal numerical values but as I am using it in redirect, it doesn't work. Let me show you the code.

Comment: Btw, what's the code snippet of your page redirect?

Comment: I guess I'm confused... if you are calling your shortcode inside a WordPress page, then the function used to replace your shortcode IS being called within the loop.  It's only if you use `<?php echo do_shortcode('[myshortcode']); ?>` that you might be outside the loop.  Have you tried just adding `global $post;` and then using `$post->ID`?

Comment: @RenCamp, I solved the problem already. You might want to checkout.

Comment: @DanielC, I solved the problem already. You might want to checkout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. Yet, I am not really sure of what the problem was. Like I mentioned, I was working in a plugin. Here is the code that was supposed to redirect.

```
// This is in the plugin's Initialize function.
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wc_custom_redirect_after_purchase' ); 

function wc_custom_redirect_after_purchase() {
    global $wp, $wpdb;

    $PageID = $wpdb->get_var('SELECT ID FROM '.$table_prefix.'posts WHERE post_content LIKE "%[myshortcode]%" AND post_parent = 0');

    if ( is_checkout() && ! empty( $wp->query_vars['order-received'] ) ) {
        $order_id  = absint( $wp->query_vars['order-received'] );
        $order_key = wc_clean( $_GET['key'] );

        /**
         * Replace {PAGE_ID} with the ID of your page
         */
        $redirect  = get_permalink($PageID);
        $redirect .= get_option( 'permalink_structure' ) === '' ? '&' : '?';
        $redirect .= 'order=' . $order_id . '&key=' . $order_key. '&noredirect=1';
            wp_redirect( $redirect );       
        exit;
    }
}
```

I am not sure what the problem was but I was always getting page redirection in endless way. Then I surfed over internet and found out that "Page not redirecting properly" could mean your redirect function is always redirecting back to the page itself. So it is a never ending loop. One of the causes was when there is a **null value** being passed to the redirect function.

I did **var_dump($PageID)** and whola, it was passing null.

You must be thinking I was nuts to not to check that earlier but I did. I used the same code and placed it in another file and I was getting $PageID = 1 (as I explained in my question). Not really sure why the VERY SAME code was returning null in my plugin file.

I changed this line

```
$PageID = $wpdb->get_var('SELECT ID FROM '.$table_prefix.'posts WHERE post_content LIKE "%[myshortcode]%" AND post_parent = 0');
```

to this directly

```
$PageID = $wpdb->get_var('SELECT ID FROM '.$wpdb->prefix.'posts WHERE post_content LIKE "%[myshortcode]%" AND post_parent = 0');
```

and yes, the redirect was successful this time.

I am still not sure why the former $PageID query was working in other files but not in my plugin file. So, I didn't have actually learnt anything. It was just hit and trial and I got lucky.

Hoping that someone would point out the actual cause. Till then, I can happily live with it. Thank you **Ren and Daniel** for taking time to respond.